# How to show Loading Div for asp.net web forms using JQuery before the entire page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <link href="Content/style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <div class="entirebody" id="total">
         </div>
    <div class="loadingdiv" id="box">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

jQueryCode

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //$("cssload-box-loading").fadeIn(1000);
    $('#box').fadeOut(8000);
});
```

The above is the code i am using the Problem with the above code is Loading div is appearing only on Page Load.

I want Loading Div immediately after placing URL and hitting Enter.

Comment: You can try using pace.js library available on http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ if you want to add page loaders. There are many customisation options present in pace.js plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am good with the animation but i need animation to show immediately after browser starts loading so that i can hide it on Jquery.onload().